# How to Iterate through Column Names from execute sql results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I'm trying to iterate through each column name from my results to place in the first row of my view. I'm using the execute sql way to querying the database.

I've got this so far but it's not outputting what I need:

```
<% for columns in @results %>
  <tr>
    <% @results.each do |column, value| %>
      <td><%= column %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does your query result look like?

Comment: Question is, I'm trying to iterate each "column name" to a table cell. The query can be different depending what the user selects as conditions. So how would i go about iterating through each column name per result?

Answer (score 4):

For the people coming here 2.5 years after this was asked, I was able to do this with Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3-p194:

```
result=ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT id AS 'user_id', first_name AS 'name' FROM users LIMIT 1")
result.each do |row|
  row.each do |k, v|
    puts "column #{k} contains #{v}"
  end
end
```

Result:

```
column user_id contains 1
column name contains Me
[{"user_id"=>1, "name"=>"Me"}]
```

Access it:

```
result.first["user_id"]
```

And if there are 3 results and you want to get the 2nd one:

```
result[1]["user_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up: MySQL/Ruby (http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/) if you're iterating a MySQL database. Other databases, look up the other drivers. Speaking purely about MySQL/Ruby, the result returned is a `Mysql::Result`.

You iterate this using `each_hash` and the block yields a hash for the row. You can then iterate the hash using each_pair. E.g.:

```
result = MyModel.connection.execute('select * from foos')
result.each_hash do |row|
  row.each_pair do |k, v|
    puts "column #{k} contains #{v}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I changed the code example. Notice that it uses `result.each_hash` to get a hash for the row. Then it iterates the hash using `each_pair` getting the key (column name) and value.